# Can an autocmd be turned on/off?

Tags: vim

I have follwing in my .vimrc to hightlight all words that matches the one on current cursor

```
autocmd CursorMoved * silent! exe printf('match Search /\<%s\>/', expand('<cword>'))
```

But sometimes it is a little annoying, so I'd like to map a key to turn on or off it, e.g. `<F10>`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in your .vimrc:

```
let g:toggleHighlight = 0
function! ToggleHighlight(...)
  if a:0 == 1 "toggle behaviour
    let g:toggleHighlight = 1 - g:toggleHighlight
  endif

  if g:toggleHighlight == 0 "normal action, do the hi
    silent! exe printf('match Search /\<%s\>/', expand('<cword>'))
  else
    "do whatever you need to clear the matches
    "or nothing at all, since you are not printing the matches
  endif
endfunction

autocmd CursorMoved * call ToggleHighlight()
map <F8> :call ToggleHighlight(1)<CR>
```

The idea is, if you call the function with an argument it changes the behavior to print/no print. 
The autocommand just uses the last setting because the function there is called without an argument.

Comment: Thanks. I'd prefer a `call clearmatches()` in the `else` block.

Answer (score 4):

Clear the autocommand and remove highlight:

```
nmap <f8> :autocmd! CursorMoved<cr> :call clearmatches()<cr>
```

and to turn it back on using a different key:

```
nmap <f9> :autocmd CursorMoved * silent! exe printf('match Search /\<%s\>/', expand('<cword>'))<cr>
```

Comment: Pretty simple way, but it couldn't turn the highlight back on when pressing `<F8>` again.

Comment: to turn back on you can at least do `nmap <f9> :autocmd CursorMoved * silent! exe printf('match Search /\<%s\>/', expand('<cword>'))<cr>`. I think it is also possible to do a toggle key though.